# Why process terminates abnormally without coredump?

Tags: linux, coredump

I have stuck in a such problem that my c++ server program **can't coredump when terminate abnormally**. The program running in [daemon](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) mode with chdir to '/'.

I had done the following things:

1. ulimit -c unlimited, so coredump enabled.
2. echo "/tmp/coredump/core.%e.%p.%t" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern, and chmod a+w coredump, so it has the permission to write coredump file.

and I had try such things:

1. send a SIGABRT via kill -6, it can coredump.
2. in dmesg, I can't find any info about the abnormally terminates process.
3. running the program not in daemon mode.

My OS version: CentOS release 6.4 (Final), x86_64

ps. the server program installed a signal handler (sigaction() with flag SA_RESETHAND) to catch such signals {SIGHUP, SIGINT, SIGQUIT, SIGTERM} for normally terminates(free resources). so it can exclude the signal shielding.

Comment: What are the permissions on your /tmp/coredump/ directory ?

Comment: done: chmod a+w coredump

Comment: while that would normally do the trick (as long as your umask was the default when /tmp/coredumps/ was created), do double check that it does have the proper permissions. It's either a permission problem, or the process is run from somwhere else where your `ulimit -c unlimited` is not in effect (e.g. from an init script, or from another shell, etc.) or some code have installed a signal handler that does not coredump for SIGABRT)

Comment: ulimit -c unlimited is confirmed effected. I will show the signal handler code later.

Comment: then I would suggest you run this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zVGLnnBv in the 100% same context as your own code and check if it behaves the same, and whether the /tmp/coredump/lim.txt looks proper.

Comment: your program behaves rightly, and I have tried by the similar way before. my server program can coredump by kill -6 when running normally. the troublesome is that the server program exit abnormally, and it can't find any reason, no coredump, no signals catched. thanks for your efforts! it may has other reasons.

Comment: it's ofcourse possible it's just calling exit() somewhere, but if it does get a SIGABRT or similar, and don't coredump, there might be a signal handler installed that inhibits the default action of that signal to coredump.

Comment: but no signal catched, I will check if exit() called somewhere via atexit().